# Can't create IBAction connections in Xcode 5 Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uistepper

A seemingly very basic problem, but it's frustrating me to no end and stalling progress. When I click and drag from a `UIButton` or `UIStepper` onto the View Controller, the option to add `IBAction` connections aren't listed.

The View Controller is called `BuyNowVC` and in my `BuyNowVC.h` I have:

```
@interface BuyNowVC : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *buyButton;
    IBOutlet UIStepper *myStepper;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *buyButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIStepper *myStepper;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed;
- (IBAction)stepperPressed;
```

And in `BuyNowVC.m`:

```
@synthesize buyButton;
@synthesize myStepper;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    NSLog(@"Button pressed!");
}

- (IBAction)stepperPressed {
    NSLog(@"Stepper pressed!");
}
```

I'm definitely ctrl dragging onto the View Controller itself but the only options I get with both `UIButton` and `UIStepper` are Action Segue: push, modal, custom. No sign of `buttonPressed` or `stepperPressed`.

**Edit**

I should also mention that this isn't the root VC and the `UIButton` is currently tied to a Segue to the next View Controller (so I can navigate my mockup) but it doesn't seem to make a difference if I remove it.

Comment: Try to add the sender: - (IBAction)buttonPressed : (id) sender

Comment: @ahmedalkaff, You don't need the sender for iOS development.

Comment: Check the custom class setting of your viewController?

Comment: The type of the viewController you are dragging to are BuyNowVC? If it's the correct type try going in to the connections inspector (far left) of the button and drag from one of the actions, usually touchupinside. If nothing works restart xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***First***, should `BuyNow.m` be `BuyNowVC.m`?

***Second***, if you are trying to tie an `UIButton` to an `IBAction` within your view controller and if that doesn't work, you might have missed re-naming the "Custom Class" field with the name of the view controller you try to connect the `UIButton` to in storyboard.

***Third***, you mentioned ".... are Action Segue: `push`, `modal`, `custom`. No sign of `buttonPressed` or `stepperPressed`.". This information tells me that you are trying to <kbd>control</kbd> drag your `UIButton` onto *another* view controller, onto which you try to tie the `IBAction` there - that is not possible.

***Adding Screenshot:***

[image]

***Please check here in storyboard:***

You have changed the "Custom Class" name for the `UIButton` to your own button name.

Please change it back to `UIButton` as name for "Custom Class" Field.

***See ScreenShot:***

Don't do this like in the image. Change it back to `UIButton`. Once you have done so, you will see "Action Connection" waving "Hi" at you again upon <kbd>control</kbd>-Dragging to it.

***Steps:***

**1.)** Click on your `UIButton` on your view controller in storyboard.

**2.)** Check the right-hand side panel (3rd tab from left) and change the "Custom Class" Field back to `UIButton`.

[image]

***So it should be:***

[image]

Comment: First: apologies, that was a mistake in the question - have edited it.
Second: checked, and the custom class is `BuyNowVC`.
Third: No, I'm ctrl dragging into the `UIButton`'s own View Controller and it gives me those options.

Comment: Here's how it shows for me if I ctrl drag from the `UIButton` in Storyboard to `.h` http://i.imgur.com/KyurmXC.png

Comment: @Sebastian Pleasure. I learnt something as well. Your image gave me a clue.

Answer (score 1):

[image: It is how I normally do it]

It is how I normally do it:

While the storyboard is open,

1) Select the middle icon ('Assistant')

2) Unselect the right pane

3) Drag from the button to the ViewController editor while holding the control key. You will notice a small cocentric circle at line 10.

Comment: Trying that gives me the option of Outlet and Outlet Connection, but not Action.

Comment: Same here, Sebastian.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the other answer... dragging into the @interface section of code gives you an outlet.  Drag into the @implementation section to get an action.

Sorry I can't post the screen print.  Not enough 'reputation' :(